# ReactJS Routing - Update Router, when Router and Link are in separate components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner in ReactJS. I have been experiencing problems with the code below, which I have written:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <button>
            <Link to = "/home">Home</Link>
          </button>
          <button>
            <Link to = "/portfolio">Portfolio</Link>
          </button>
        </Router>
      </div>;
    )
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/home">
              <h1>Home</h1>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/portfolio">
              <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>;
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var element = (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Content />
      </div>;
    )
    return element;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Problem:**

I would like the `render()` function of `Content` component to change every time a user clicks on a Link from the `Navigation` component. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't to wrap your `Navigation` component with Router. As is only the `links` that will navigate to the component. And another thing is wrap your `App` component with main `BrowserRouter` which i guess you have imported as `Router` here.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <button>
            <Link to = "/home">Home</Link>
          </button>
          <button>
            <Link to = "/portfolio">Portfolio</Link>
          </button>
      </div>;
    )
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/home">
              <h1>Home</h1>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/portfolio">
              <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>;
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<Router>
      <Navigation />
      <Content />
    </Router>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Hope this works for you.